# Pointer to template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class, I have a ptr to that template class in my main class. The ptr can be of 2 types (`type1` and `type2`). I want to be able to call `someMethod()` in template class without checking for `type1` or `type2`. Can that be done?

I could maintain 2 separate pointers, so in addition to `tc_`, `unique_ptr<TemplateClass<type2>> tc2_` in `MainClass`. Then check the type before calling `tc_->someMethod()` or `tc2->someMethod()`.

But I would like to avoid that. Is there a known pattern to solve this? Is maintaining 2 separate pointers in `MainClass` the only option or can I have some level of indirection so `MainClass` only has one

```
template<class Context>
class TemplateClass {
 void someMethod(Context c) {
 ...
 }
};
```

```
class MainClass {
 explicit MainClass(Options opts): opts_(opts){
 tc_ = make_unique<TemplateClass<type1>();
}
 unique_ptr<TemplateClass<type1>> tc_;
 Options opts_;


};
```

edit: To complicate matters type2 is also a template class. So I have `unique_ptr<TemplateClass<std::variant<type1, type2<SpecialType2>>>> tc_` How can I access someMethod? `tc_->someMethod` does not work, do I need to use `std::visit` in this case? I don't know much about std::visit, can someone point me to an example?

Comment: Have both template class declarations conform to the same interface with a purely virtual function. Then you can have a pointer to that interface and initialize it with the instance of whatever template it is.. so you can call the functions through the pointer. IE: Both classes inherit the same interface. Example: https://ideone.com/hnUaFq

Comment: You can also use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: `TemplateClass<type1>` and `TemplateClass<type2>` are unrelated class (even if they come from template `TemplateClass`).

Comment: How are you intending on calling `someMethod` without any parameters? It takes a `Context`

Comment: Lets say I have `unique_ptr<TemplateClass<std::variant<type1, type2>>> tc_` , how can I access `someMethod` tc_->someMethod() or using std::visit?